# ORA-29875 error on serial inserting into full text indexed table

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working on utility that adds all files in directory as entries to database and indexes them. My code itself works fine, but after exactly 297 inserts (always, checked on another document collection) i got following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29875: nie uda?o si? wykona? podprogramu ODCIINDEXINSERT
ORA-20000: 
DRG-50857: 
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:initialization failed
ORA-06512: przy "CTXSYS.DRUE", linia 160
ORA-06512: przy "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", linia 756
```

Any ideas what could be cause of this error?

In my table there is FTINDEX column and entries have this value set to IGNORE.

Using Java 1.7, Eclipse, Oracle 12c, OJDBC6 Driver.

Comment: Maybe you must include your table definition, your code for inserting a new row and the specific data that is causing the exception i.e the 297th file properties to be stored.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks, i will include some data. However it's not problem with a file itself as i tried to swap it with first one, process still failed.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2453451?tstart=0) and its "correct" answer on OTN. I don't know if this applies in your case but it might be helpful. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks a lot for a clue, meanwhile i found a cause - it was unclosed cursor. I was just confused by error message. :)